# How To Add Sort To Yii2 Gridview for "multi" relational attributes

Tags: php, database, gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i have a question in `Yii2 Gridview`

for example when we have relations like **this** :

```
car -> model -> brand -> company -> company_title
```

the `company_title` in `gridview` is not clickable and i can't sort it by `asc` or `desc`

how i can do it?

Comment: [Yii2 Gridview Sorting Relation Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUUQNbQ3TS8)

Answer (score 0):

In data provider for each sorting row define sorting rules:

```
    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['loadDate'] = [
        'asc' => ['status_load.status_time' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['status_load.status_time' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['supplyingInvoiceNumber'] = [
        'asc' => ['cmd_delivery_osta.supplying_invoice_number' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['cmd_delivery_osta.supplying_invoice_number' => SORT_DESC],
    ];
```